# Get a newly virtual generated UUID from insert statement

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. Im using MySQL stored procedure to run two queries at once.

i am inserting a client record and i assign the client a virtual generated UUID and im trying to insert into another table at the same time the newly created ID along with the user id (the user who created the client).

Creating the field for virtual UUID rather than storing on the server

```
    client_id        varchar(36) generated always as
        (insert(
                insert(
                        insert(
                                insert(hex(id_bin), 9, 0, '-'),
                                14, 0, '-'),
                        19, 0, '-'),
                24, 0, '-')
        ) virtual,
    id_bin         binary(16)
```

Insert the virtual generated ID

```
unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', ''))
```

I've tried using **last_insert_id()** but since my id is not auto incrementing, it doesnt help.
I've also tried

```
select * from client_info where client_id in (select max(client_id) from client_info);
```

my stored procedure is something like this (shortened to show needed fields):

```
create procedure addClient(

    in puser_id varchar(36),
    in pname varchar(255)
)
BEGIN

    insert into client_info (id_bin, f_name) values (unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', '')), pname);
    insert into clients (user_id, client_id) values (puser_id, XXXX)
        END
    //
DELIMITER ;
```

unsure how to insert the new client ID into the second insert statement that shows XXXX in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable, so you can use it in both INSERT statements.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_uuid BINARY(16);

    SET new_uuid = unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', ''));

    insert into client_info (id_bin, f_name) values (new_uuid, pname);
    insert into clients (user_id, client_id) values (puser_id, new_uuid);
END
```

Comment: i thought was going to be the fix. while this does now put it into the table, the column stays as binary to which when i "select * from clients where client_id = "04ff670b-7da8-11ee-aec6-36c791f19594" then it doesnt show the result.
i am starting to thing the whole generated as virtual thing is more of a headache than just storing the UUID on the server

Comment: Ah, i figured it out by adding one more line thanks to your help with line 3! Much appreciated!